# Classifying field extensions of of function field of degree $2$

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $F$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $2$.

I am wondering if the only extensions of $F(t)$, isomorphic to $F(t)$ over $F$ are given by the Frobenius $F(\sqrt t) / F(t)$ and the separable extension $F(t)[x]/(x^2+tx+t^2+t)/F(t)$ up to isomorphism (in the sense of allowing isomorphism both of the source and target field).

In characteristic $0$ this holds by Hurwitz theory (while the case of geometric Frobenius cannot exist), but for example $\mathbb{Q}$ has a lot of non-isomorphic extensions of degree $2$, so in the answer there must be at least some properties of $F(t)$ be used.

Comment: Degree-two extensions $F(t)\subset K$ (up to the right sorts of isomorphisms) are in bijection with smooth projective curves over $F$ equipped with a morphism to $\Bbb P^1_F$. In particular, every elliptic curve over $F$ gives at least one distinct extension, and there are at least $|F|$-many elliptic curves over $F$. So I'm a little unclear how you came to the claim that there are only two extensions of degree 2.

Comment: You are absolutely right that I failed to give the most important condition: That I only want to consider field extensions $L/K$ with $L$ isomorphic to $K(t)$ (over $K$).